# MVC4 Remote Validation clashes with submit button

Tags: ajax, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have a remote validator setup on my text box which primarily checks if the data that the user enters is unique. I do understand this works on mouse out of the original control and does an AJAX call for the same.

My problem is that while this works fine while am tabbing between controls on my form containing like 6 other controls, if I am directly clicking on the submit button on my form, the request does not go across since the AJAX call for the remote validation is in progress, and the user would in this scenario have to click on the submit button twice to actually save the form.

Anyone come across this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest, leave your button disabled; and only enable if all of your validations have been passed. This way, your button will only be enabled once you have got the response back from the remote validation.

Comment: I am not sure how to tap into the Remote validation that MVC does to be able to enable the button later on. Plus this problem occurs if the validation is on the first control and the mouse out goes directly to the submit button. Strangely does not happen again when tapping into the textbox.

Comment: I had a global ajax start and ajax stop event, which I was using for showing a progress loader and background blackout section, for disabling clicks and other operations. I was able to handle the remote validator ajax calls and not invoke my progress loader for these specific instances. 

That way I do not need to disable the button and handle checks for enabling the same. Thanks for the help Ali Iftikhar.